# Displaying CSS properties and values of a HtmlControl

Tags: asp.net

I have a `<div id="Result" ... >` with a bunch of CSS properties and values and I would like to display them when I click a button. This is what I currently have:

```cs
protected void Button1_OnServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Result.Style.Value.Length; i++)
    {
        Result.InnerHtml += Result.Style.Value[i];
    }
}
```

The code does display them, however, they are all displayed in a sequence of characters. I would like to get them displayed as properties and values, both with different accessing variable and all pairs on seperate row.

I messed with it for a good while but I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the Keys collection:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (String key in Result.Style.Keys)
        {
            Result.InnerHtml += key + ": " + Result.Style[key] + ";</br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is it! I knew there must be simple solution and I was pretty near in my one attempt even.